# Can't extract test statistics by $teststat from list in R

Tags: r, testing, extract

I try to extract test statistics by `$teststat` from a test that I have run 10 000 times, but than I encounter the problem:

```
library(urca)
df.test<-replicate(10000,ur.df(cumsum(rnorm(n=100, mean=0))))
```

but command

```
df.test$teststats
```

gives output: `NULL`

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an s4 object and the testsats are in slots. I think you want something like this:

```
df.test<-replicate(10,ur.df(cumsum(rnorm(n=100, mean=0))))
df.test[[1]]@teststat

#               tau1
#statistic 0.8491917
```

to get all the result then you prabably want something like

```
unlist( lapply(df.test, function(x) x@teststat))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all the `teststat` values at once in one vector, use

```
sapply(df.test, function(z) z@teststat)
```